# Should I worry about an initial negative voltage?

Tags: microcontroller, schmitt-trigger

I'm building a circuit that I found online for measuring spark-plug pulses and it seems to give a clean enough slope for my micro-controller interrupt, but it has an initial negative voltage.

Is this something I need to worry about?

[image: Schmidt trigger]

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fZCjmf.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: This negative peaks may be caused by diodes, inductors and capacitors present in the circuit. Usually there is nothing to worry about, however it may be the case that your micro is not tolerant at all about reverse polarity voltages. No particular answer can be given before you provide additional info.

Comment: Okay, if it helps I have a Schmidt trig output into a nano-farad cap for smoothing before going to an mBed micro-controller. There are other parts, but those seemed to be the important parts.

Comment: Couldn't find a datasheet with electrical ratings for mBed.

Comment: Can you explain what's going on with Q1 & D2 in your schematic. Or maybe link to where you found the circuit so we can see if they explain it?

Comment: Sorry if I messed it up. I got it from these circuit boards, http://uploads.oshpark.com/uploads/project/top_image/jKTStKVf/i.png, http://uploads.oshpark.com/uploads/project/bottom_image/jKTStKVf/i.png

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using mBed then according to the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mbed_microcontroller) article it probably uses an LPC1768 for which your favorite Internet search engine easily finds a [datasheet](http://www.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/LPC1769_68_67_66_65_64_63.pdf).

Within the datasheet search for `Absolute Maximum` (sometimes `Electrical specification`).

There is a Symbol called V<sub>I</sub> "input voltage". The description says:

> 5V tolerant I/O pins; only valid when the V<sub>DD(3V3)</sub> supply voltage is present.

These pins are rated (absolute maximum) for **-0.5V ... +5.5V**, meaning that anything lower than -0.5V or higher than +5.5V may destroy your controller. It also means that if the voltage is well within this spec, you don't have to worry.

To ensure your input will be within the given limits, you should consider using diodes to clamp the input to the power rails. Notice that your scope *may* not catch the highest peak!

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fobarW.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The Schottky diodes have a low voltage drop, well below the 0.5V room required.

Comment: "your scope may not catch the highest", yeah, it's not the best scope ever. I added a 4148 diode to the output, but it made the rest of the signal all wobbly(I can take a pic). Is that normal? I thought they would just eliminate negative voltage. Should I have put it before the "smoothing" capacitor?

Comment: You'll have to add a circuit diagram to be able to answer that. Also a 1N4148 will limit to about 0.6 or 0.7V which is too high.

Comment: I could not find a good object for the schmitt trigger, so you'll have to imagine it's something else...